# What is the benefit of defining forms as services in symfony 2

Tags: php, forms, symfony, dependency-injection

Is there any benefit of defining forms as services in Symfony 2? According to symfony [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#defining-your-forms-as-services) it is a good practice but what can I gain by doing so. E.g: performance, usability etc.

Based on the documentation I don't see that much difference using

```
$form = $this->createForm('task', $task);
```

instead of

```
$form = $this->createForm(new TaskType(), $task);
```

Comment: It's to promote reuse and to reduce the amount of code in the controller for form creation. http://www.webtipblog.com/define-a-symfony-2-form-as-a-service/

Comment: Suppose you have several forms of `TaskType()` in you application, suddenly you need to use `SuperTaskType()` for form. What is simplier - search all project for code `new TaskType()` or redefine service in yml-file?

Comment: A major benefit occurs when you need to inject additional services into your forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Services can be overriden, allowing a bundle to customize a specific form of a 3th party bundle.
- Form types are stateless. Using them as services would allow them to be only initialized once and reused each next time. Without services, you need to initialize the class each time you use it.
- Forms as services can be customized by global settings, parameters and other services.